# Extract integer value from url string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to extract specific integer value from a given string 
e.g.

```
http://start.mysearchdial.com/results.php?q=hovercrafting+manchester&category=web&a=coolmsd&f=2&cd=2&XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0&cr=1818627175&uref=14&start=1
```

From the above string I want to extract '2' from 'cd=2' part of string. The code I am using is

```
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(4000) 
SET @URL = 'http://start.mysearchdial.com/results.php?q=hovercrafting+manchester&category=web&a=coolmsd&f=2&cd=2&XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0&cr=1818627175&uref=14&start=1'
SELECT Case WHEN CHARINDEX('cd=',@URL)>0 
    THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@URL,CHARINDEX('cd=',@URL),CHARINDEX('cd=',@URL)-1),4,CHARINDEX('&',SUBSTRING(@URL,CHARINDEX('cd=',@URL),CHARINDEX('cd=',@URL)-1))-4) 
    ELSE NULL 
END
```

Now this works fine as long as '&' appears after integer part. Sometimes there is no '&' sign and then this gives exception.

Can someone help on how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the database? Surely there's some other code involved which has better text processing facilities than SQL? Also, if you do insist on an SQL solution, what database system are you using? (Looks like SQL Server maybe, but not 100% sure)

Comment: @user467710 what are the other characters that may appear after integer part?

Comment: Its SQL Server 2008, i am using this in stored procedure.

Comment: @user467710 i am not sure about other characters but mostly its 'X' that appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this to extract the text:

```
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(4000) 
SET @URL = 'http://start.mysearchdial.com/results.php?q=hovercrafting+manchester&category=web&a=coolmsd&f=2&cd=2&XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0&cr=1818627175&uref=14&start=1'

DECLARE @QSXML xml
SET @QSXML = CAST('<a><b>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@URL,CHARINDEX('?',@URL)+1,4000),'&','</b><b>') + '</b></a>' as xml)

select
    SUBSTRING(c.value('.','varchar(4000)'),4,4000)
from @QSXML.nodes('/a/b') t(c)
where
    c.value('.','varchar(4000)') like 'cd=%'
```

The reason I'd do it like this is in case I need to extract more than one value from the query string - the final `SELECT` can be switched around to produce a table of keys and values. (I would have done so already, but the `XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0` parameter doesn't have a value and I couldn't decide what to do with it).

---

This is the alternative query (still using `@QSXML` as above) that gives a tabular result:

```
;With ShreddedNodes as (
    select
        c.value('.','varchar(4000)') as ParmAndValue
    from @QSXML.nodes('/a/b') t(c)
), Splits as (
    select ParmAndValue,CHARINDEX('=',ParmAndValue) as Split
    from ShreddedNodes
), KeysAndValues as (
    select
        CASE WHEN Split > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(ParmAndValue,1,Split-1)
        ELSE
            ParmAndValue
        END as [Key],
        CASE WHEN Split > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(ParmAndValue,Split+1,4000)
        END as Value
    from Splits
)
select * from KeysAndValues
```

Produces:

```
Key                                Value
---------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
q                                  hovercrafting+manchester
category                           web
a                                  coolmsd
f                                  2
cd                                 2
XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0             NULL
cr                                 1818627175
uref                               14
start                              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(4000) 

SET @URL = 
'http://start.mysearchdial.com/results.php?q=hovercrafting+manchester&category=web&a=coolmsd&f=2&XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0&cr=1818627175&uref=14&start=1&cd=2'

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Charindex('cd=', @URL) > 0 THEN 
           CASE 
             WHEN Charindex('&', @URL, Charindex('cd=', @URL) + 3) > 0 THEN 
             Substring(@URl, Charindex('cd=', @URL) + 3, Charindex('&', @URL, 
           Charindex('cd=', 
           @URL) + 3) - Charindex('cd=', @URL) - 3) 
             ELSE Substring(@URL, Charindex('cd=', @URL) + 3, 
                         Len(@URL) - Charindex('cd=', @URL) + 3) 
           END 
         ELSE NULL 
       END 

go
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to append '&' (with CONCAT or what your DB-System need for that) on url in every case

```
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(4000) 
SET @URL = 'http://start.mysearchdial.com/results.php?q=hovercrafting+manchester&category=web&a=coolmsd&f=2&cd=2&XzuyEtN2Y1L1QzuyEzzyD0&cr=1818627175&uref=14&start=1'
SELECT Case WHEN CHARINDEX('cd=',@URL)>0 
    THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(CONCAT(@URL, '&'),CHARINDEX('cd=',CONCAT(@URL, '&')),CHARINDEX('cd=',CONCAT(@URL, '&'))-1),4,CHARINDEX('&',SUBSTRING(CONCAT(@URL, '&'),CHARINDEX('cd=',CONCAT(@URL, '&')),CHARINDEX('cd=',CONCAT(@URL, '&'))-1))-4) 
    ELSE NULL 
END
```